# Design of fan pipe for propelling glitter

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, design, airflow

I am trying to create a prototype for a glitter shooting mechanism. It is worth mentioning that I have no experience with mechanical engineering or fluid dynamics. I think the below image describes the situation very well:

[image]

The fan is considerably wider than the diameter of the pipe so I just visually designed a connecting pipe from the fan to the PVC pipe. The goal is to have the fan blow glitter up through the longer section of pipe and out the top. The glitter will initially be stored in the bottom of the bend, not blocking the air passage completely.

Currently, the issue I see is that a lot of air is coming back out through the inlet shooting almost sideways out once it leaves the fan. I was considering adding a pipe section with the same dimensions as the fan to direct the flow into the inlet and prevent the air from squeezing out through the sides (i.e. forcing it against the air being sucked in). Would this work?

How can I maximize the ability of the fan to push glitter given access to more PVC pipe and a 3D printer?

Comment: You need a radial fan, not an axial fan - this is essentially a loaded leaf blower.

Comment: [Garden Dust Applicator](https://www.agrisupply.com/garden-dust-applicator/p/34878/?sid=asf10&eid=Easf10&zmam=77232640&zmas=1&zmac=1&zmap=34878&eid=gl020116&sid=google&gclid=Cj0KCQiA4NTxBRDxARIsAHyp6gA7u0BhuVP6F1DTUGEvevfiXW3U6bctuWM0YXqyfx1C5uGcIKhoo4YaAgi8EALw_wcB)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, folks. I've seen some designs for electric leaf blowers that use an axial fan but in general anything that needs to push hard uses a radial fan.